# Convert an unknown structure to an untyped Object in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I'd like to convert an unknown basic structure to an Object (no type here).

I'm building a library that will be used by many users to extract data from my system but don't want to do a new function for everyone of them. They have to know what will be the result.

In vb, it is possible to create an Object with some properties and use it as it is a regular Class like so:

```
Dim myObj as New With { .name = "Matt", .age = "28" }
MsgBox( myObj.name & " is now " & myObj.age & " years old.")
```

So far, so good.

Next step : my user will give me some instructions that I need to extract data from various DBs, and I've no idea of what the result will be.

What I know after the execution is a list of String containing the columns of the result set and, of course a (set of) rows.

And here is the problem of course

My function (for a single row) so far:

```
Public Function GetData(ByVal instructions as String) as Object ' User is supposed to know what will be inside, instructions is as XML describing DB, table, query, ...
   ' Do what is needed to retrieve data
   ' Here I have a variable cols As List(Of String) ' e.g. ("BP", "NAME", "VAT")
   Dim o As New With ???
   Return o
End Function
```

What I've tried: build a fake JSon on the fly, and try to Deserialize to Object.
But even if it seems to work, I (and the user) can't access the property as in my top piece of code like:

```
MsgBox(o.BP)
```

I know that I could do

```
Public Function GetData(Of T As {New})(ByVal instructions as String) As T
   Dim o As T
   ' Use some Reflexion to TryInvokeMember of T
   Return o
End Function
```

But I wanted to remove the hassle to create a class to use my code.
Plus, My librairy will be use in a webservice and the class of the user is then unknown.

Comment: Have you considered manually creating a [DataTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable?view=net-5.0) or some other data structure that can be dynamically populated. End users of your library shouldn't really have to deal with raw `Objects`.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject?view=net-5.0?

Comment: What does `instructions` look like?

Comment: instructions is an xml representation about how to extract data, like 
source type (DB, File, SAP), name (table, function module, file name, ...)
extra filtering to apply (where clause, regexp in CSV, ...)
output format (object(s), excel, datatable, file, DB, ...) with parameters (file name, connection string.
I'm serializing those instructions and process in 2 main steps: 
 1. extraction depending on source and filtering (where clause for DB or regexp in files for exemple)
 2. creating the output (a file, a table in a DB, a datatable, an object, a list of object).

Comment: Bordering on opinion here, but I think you're making your own problem here.  If you're building a standard library to query data, then make it's results standard too.  It's the consumers responsibility to shape the data to meet the consumer requirements.

Comment: @Hursey, unfortunately, my manager asked me to do any kind of input/output, even the stupidest. Therefore, I'm here, wondering how I can can create an unknow object from an unknow structure, I know ... Maybe I'll give-up after a while and tell him that it is not reasonable in a time/budget perspective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @GSerg, @Fabio and a few other searches about ExpandoObject, I did it !

```
Imports System.Dynamic  

Dim o As Object = New ExpandoObject()
For Each col In cols
    DirectCast(o, IDictionary(Of String, Object)).Add(col, row.GetString(col))
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be - to use `Dictionary(Of String, Object)`

```
Public Function GetData(instructions as String) As Dictionary(Of String, Object)
    Dim data = ' Load data
    Dim columns As String() = { "BP", "NAME", "VAT" }

    Return columns.ToDictionary(
        Function(column) column,
        Function(column) data.GetByColumnName(column)
    )
End Function

` Usage

Dim result = GetDate("instructions: ['BP', 'NAME']")
' Because user knows it is Integer
Dim bpValue = DirectCast(result.Item("BP"), Integer)
```

Comment: The idea of the IDictionary(of String, Object) is good, I used it in combination with ExpandoObject. Thank you for your help.